# How to avoid users choose files with an extension other than allowed ones?

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I have an OpenFileDialog that has defined a Filter for allowed extensions(only image files like jpg, png and so on). 
The issue is that our user can type *.* in file Name textbox and then this will filter for all files. Then I can choose a text file without any problem.
Is there a way to allow not this to happen except a code behind block that will check for allowed extension?
This is the block I created that may help you understand the issue, also:

```
if (!(ImageFileExtensions.Split(new char[] { ',' }).Contains(Path.GetExtension(currentFileNamePath).Replace(".", ""))) )
{
    DialogResult respNotAllowedExtension = MdtUserMessage.ShowError(GenericLogCommon.GenericLogDettType.UserWarning, "The extension of the file is not allowed!" , MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    if (respNotAllowedExtension == DialogResult.OK)
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible because files can indeed have misleading extensions - and if a user knows that a certain file (say `.dat`) actually contains a loadable file format (say PNG), what would be the point of blocking him/her from opening the file? Likewise, the correct file extension is not a guarantee that the file contents is valid, hence file extension filters are usually just a visual convenience that can be overridden by users rather than something securely enforced.

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no other way.

Comment: See if its possible to customise the OpenFIleDialog and override the keypress event over the text box (File name). If its possible, then you can disallow user from entering . char. Hope i understood your problem correctly.

Comment: ok, thanks for your replies. I remain at the implementation I did. Regards.